# Problema con REGEX en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy haciendo un regex que me permita lo letras (incluye ñ y vocales con tilde) y ciertos caracteres especiales. El problema es que el sistema no me permite el ingreso de las tildes pero si de la ñ....

```
    var texto       = $("#"+div+"").val();
    var expresion   = new RegExp(/[^A-Za-z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\u00f1\u00d1\/\-()_\r\n\t\f ]/g);
    $("#"+div+"").val(texto.replace(expresion,""));
}
```

el `\u00f1\u00d1` me acepta la ñÑ

Comment: intenté con este codigo \u00E0-\u00FC  para las tildes pero también me acepta los  æßðđŋħ

Comment: Pon los códigos individuales de cada vocal acentuada: `\u00C1\u00C9\u00D3\u00DA` etc. Puedes verlos todos [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout) pues ISO-8859-1 es compatible con Unicode (tiene los mismos códigos).

Comment: O añade una `u` en las opciones de la regexp, para que te admita el texto en utf8. O sea `RegExp(/..../gu)`

Comment: gracias!!

quedó de esta manera
 var expresion  = new RegExp(/[^A-Za-z0-9 \u00C1\u00C9\u00CD\u00D3\u00DA\u00E1\u00E9\u00ED\u00F3\u00FA\u00f1\u00d1 \/\-|.()N/n\r\n\t\f ]/g);

Comment: @abulafia y Juan Pablo, quizás alguno podría escribir la respuesta para que pueda ser aceptada :)

Answer (score 0):

Al final la Respuesta quedó así

var expresion = new RegExp(/[^A-Za-z0-9 \u00C1\u00C9\u00CD\u00D3\u00DA\u00E1\u00E9\u00ED\u00F3\u00FA\u00f1\u00d1 /-|.()N/n\r\n\t\f ]/g);

y los codigos de las letras las pueden obtener desde este [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout)